# How to send messages from Kafka producer on one PC to kafka broker on another PC?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to send messages from Kafka Producer on one PC to Kafka broker on another PC using ***wifi interfaces***, but messages don't appear in the specified topic at Kafka broker.

I connected two PCs using ASUS wireless router and disabled all the firewalls on PCs and router. Both PCs ping successfully each other. When I turn to a wired connection, it works and messages are ingested to the specified topic on kafka broker pc.

Kafka Producer:

```
public class CarDataProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CarDataProducer fProducer= new CarDataProducer();
        Producer<String, CarData> producer= fProducer.initializeKafkaProducer();

        String topicName = "IN-DATA";

        CSVReaderCarData csvReader = new CSVReaderCarData();
        List<CarData> CarDataList = csvReader.readCarDataFromCSV("data/mllib/TrainTest_101.csv");

        //read from CSV file and send
        for (CarData val : CarDataList) {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, CarData>(topicName, val));
        }
    }

    public KafkaProducer<String, CarData> initializeKafkaProducer() {

        // Set the producer configuration properties.
        Properties props = ProducerProperties.getInstance();

        // Instantiate a producerSampleJDBC
        KafkaProducer<String, CarData> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, CarData>(props);

        return producer;
    }

public class ProducerProperties {
    private ProducerProperties() {
    }

    public static final Properties props = new Properties();
    static {
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.124:9092");
        props.put("acks", "0");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 500);
        props.put("linger.ms", 500);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 500);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "com.iov.safety.vehicleproducer.CarDataSerializer");
    }

    public static Properties getInstance() {
        return props;
    }
}
```

Check message reception via Kafka Consumer using console on the server-side:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic IN-DATA
```

The reception of messages should look like this:

```
 kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.1.124:9092 --topic IN-DATA
{"instSpeed":19.0,"time":15.0,"label":0.0}
{"instSpeed":64.0,"time":15.0,"label":1.0}
{"instSpeed":10.0,"time":16.0,"label":0.0}
```

ifconfig on server side

---

[image: ifconfig on server side]

ipconfig on kafka producer side

---

### [image: ipconfig on kafka producer side]

- server.properties:

---

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

- netstat -ano|grep '9092'

---

> tcp6       0      0 :::9092                 :::*
>   LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0) tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:53880
>   127.0.1.1:9092          ESTABLISHED keepalive (6659.53/0/0) tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:9092          127.0.0.1:53880         ESTABLISHED
>   keepalive (6659.53/0/0) tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:9092
>   127.0.0.1:53878         ESTABLISHED keepalive (6659.15/0/0) tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:53878         127.0.1.1:9092          ESTABLISHED
>   keepalive (6659.15/0/0)

---

By adding callback to send of kafka producer, I get timeout error:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 8 record(s) for IN-DATA-0: 30045 ms has passed since last append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Each Kafka broker has to advertise its hostname/ip, to be reachable from Kafka Producer on another pc.

```
 kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties --override  advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.124:9092
sha
```

Instead, we can update config/server.properties as follows:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
```

or

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.124:9092
```